# Excluding Members showing from member list that are already included in team

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables like 1. Users 2. Members 3. Teams.For creating a team there are some members included in team. But if leader wants to add any other member he can also add but i want to exclude those members and leaders from this list where leader can add a member.
It is my members table

```
members_id | team_id | member_id
9                8         3
11               9         5
```

teams table

```
teams_id| name| leader_id
 8       Team A    9
 9       Team B    11
```

Users table those who are members

```
id|     name|          email|            username
3  Tanvir Ahmed Hera tanvir1@gmail.com  hira
4  Shahadat         hada@gmail.com      shada
5   Nayeem          nayem@gmail.com    nayeem
```

roles table

```
id | name
3     member
```

when i click to add members it shows me 3 names which is in users table. ok, that's fine but as we can show member 3 and 5 are already assigned so i want only member whose user id is 4

My result showing is
[image: Click to show th results]

but i want to expect this

```
Select Member/s
                       shada
            //Save button here
```

I stuck here

```
$team_leaders = Team::groupBy('leader_id')->get()->pluck('leader_id');
                    $users=Member::where('team_id',$member->teams_id)->get()->pluck('member_id');
                    $members=DB::table('projects')
                        ->join('teams','projects.team_id','teams.teams_id')
                        ->join('members','teams.teams_id','members.team_id')
                        ->join('users','members.member_id','users.id')
                        ->select('users.email')->where('members.member_id',$users)
                        ->where('members.members_id','!=',$team_leaders)
                        ->groupBy('users.email')->get();
```

Comment: Could you share your code where you are having this problem?

Comment: ok wait for few minutes

Comment: i edit my questions

Comment: Try whereNotIn('members.members_id', $team_leaders) instead of  ->where('members.members_id','!=',$team_leaders)